# How to get dropdownvalues at serverside when populating the list via javascript/jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am populating a dropdownlist via jquery and I can always get the selected dropdownItem like this:

```
Request.Form[EducationTypes.UniqueID]
```

The above code is performed on a normal postback to the server.

I can't figure out how to get all the items in the list when im at the server, not just the selected one...

Is this possible? and no I do not want to do a AJAX call to the server, i want to know if this can be done when doing a normal postback.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have `<asp:HiddenField>` in your page..

Then from javascript store any value you need as the HiddenField value, then from server-side you can access the hiddenfield value on postback..

From javascript you can set multiple values as comma-delimited and parse it on server.

**Or for more complex data** you can set value as json string from Javascript by serializing some object `{}` with

```
Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(obj);
```

* you need to have a ScriptManager on page for this javascript to work

Then from code behind, Deserialize it to some class that matches the JSON structure

```
JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JSS.Deserialize<SomeClass>(JsonString);
```